# c++ how-to: import numeric variables from .txt or .csv file

Tags: c++, variables, csv, assign

still being a beginner at C++, I cannot figure out how to use `fstream`.
I want to assign values to a set of `double` variables in my program, from
a `.txt` or a `.csv` file (`.csv` might be better for practical reasons.)

Let's say that my `input_file.csv` looks like that:

```
10
0
20
0.4
0.1333382222
0
0.5
10
20
0.76
0.3
0.1
0.2
```

These values should be assigned to the following variables (first declared as equal to `0` ) in my code:

```
/// geometry
double Dist=0; ///Distance between the 2

double PosAi = 0;
double PosAo = 0;
double PosBi = 0;
double PosBo = 0; ///positions i/o

/// densities

double iDA=0;
double oDA=0;
double iDAtop=0;
double oDAtop=0; /// Left

double iDB=0;
double oDB=0;
double iDBtop=0;
double oDBtop=0; /// Right
```

I want to read the values of `input_file.csv` and assign them to my variables, so that if I type:

```
cout<<Dist<<" "<<PosAi<<" "<<PosAo<<" "<<
```

...........etc. `;`

I get the following list on the console:

```
10 0 20 0.4 0.1333382222 0 0.5 10 20 0.76 0.3 0.1 0.2
```

But I don't know how to use fsteam for that, could you please help a bit?
Thanks!

---

Ok here's the answer if ever some beginner like me gets the same problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

/// geometry

double Dist=0; ///Distance between the 2
double PosAi = 0;
double PosAo = 0;
double PosBi = 0;
double PosBo = 0; ///positions i/o

/// densities

double iDA=0;
double oDA=0;
double iDAtop=0;
double oDAtop=0; /// Left
double iDB=0;
double oDB=0;
double iDBtop=0;
double oDBtop=0; /// Right

int main()
{
ifstream ifs ("input.csv");
if (!ifs)
    // process error
ifs >> Dist;
ifs >> PosAi;
ifs >> PosAo;
ifs >> PosBi;
ifs >> PosBo;
ifs >> iDA;
ifs >> oDA;
ifs >> iDAtop;
ifs >> oDAtop;
ifs >> iDB;
ifs >> oDB;
ifs >> iDBtop;
ifs >> oDBtop;

    // print variables

    cout << Dist << " " << PosAi << " " << PosAo << " " << PosBi << " " << PosBo << " " << iDA << " " << oDA << " " << iDAtop << " " << oDAtop << " " << iDB << " " << oDB << " " << iDBtop << " " << oDBtop << endl;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Without you showing us a LITTLE bit more of what you have tried, it's hard to help you, since it's no point in me telling you how to do something you already know.

Comment: Is it more clear after this edit?

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com You don't use an `fstream` for this, you use an `ofstream`.  And you probably don't access it directly, but through an `istream&`.

Comment: Well, jsp has given an answer, which is along the lines of what I would suggest at this point (aside from "Get a book about C++")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifstream ifs ("input_file.txt");
if (!ifs)
    // process error
ifs >> DISTAB;
ifs >> POSAstart;
....
```

Comment: great! thanks. I add the code in the question for noobs like me!

Comment: btw, your input is not separated by commas, so the .csv extension is not quite accurate.  (and if you did separate the values by commas, it would only make reading them in more complicated.)

Comment: Thanks, I know I only need a .txt file for that kind of data structure. However this was just a test as I'd like to try another structure, like: `12.3, 36.45, 27.36` any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to print a bunch of variables with `cout`, you know how to read them with input streams - it's the opposite. Just reverse the arrows of your `cout` call:

```
myInputFile >> Dist >> PosAi >> PosAo >> ...;
```

NB that input streams can only take actual variables as arguments to `>>`, in contrast to output streams which can take temporaries, like how you printed the space using `<< " "`. But fortunately input streams eat whitespace automatically, so you can just ignore it. Therefore my example in the previous line is correct.

Also, `cout` is predeclared in `iostream`, but you'll need to declare your input stream. `ifstream` takes the name of the file to read as its first parameter:

```
ifstream myInputFile ("input_file.csv");
```

Comment: It's not quite the opposite.  You mention separators, which have to be explicitly output, but will be skipped implicitly on input (provided they are only white space---CVS files usually use a comma, which must be explicitly read ans skipped).  More important is that you must check that the input succeeded before you use any of the values you input; otherwise, you have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't (normally) use an `fstream` for this, you use
an `ifstream`.  And you generally don't access it directly, but
through an `istream&`; just as `ofstream` is derived from
`ostream,`ifstream`derives from`istream`, so that you can use`
istream&` independently of the type of stream.

Finally, for each `<<` operator on an `ostream`, there is
a corresponding `>>` operator on an `istream`, so if you can do
`std::cout << x`, you can do `input >> x` (but of course, you
don't normally do `std::cout << x`, you do `output << x`, where
`output` is an `ostream&` passed into the function—maybe
`std::cout`, but maybe an `std::ofstream`, or some other
`ostream`).  There are differences, of course: output is
generally easier than input, because you control the source
(your variables); input requires a lot of error checking, since
you can receive literally anything.  In particular, you cannot,
ever, use any input value until you have verified that the input
succeeded.  In the case of output, you generally only do this
once, at the end of the output (after the last flush to
`std::cout`, or after closing the `std::ofstream`).